# How do I keep only the Top n rows in a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this:

```
ID | Item |
1  | A    |
1  | B    |
2  | A    |
3  | B    |
1  | C    |
4  | C    |
5  | B    |
3  | A    |
4  | A    |
5  | D    |
```

In R, how do I keep only the Top N values (by count) in Item Column? I would also like to fill the values which are not in Top N with "Others".
Expected result if Top 2 values:

```
ID | Item   |
1  | A      |
1  | B      |
2  | A      |
3  | B      |
1  | Others |
4  | Others |
5  | B      |
3  | A      |
4  | A      |
5  | Others |
```

How do I handle tie cases too?

Comment: Not really dplyr, but can this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950119/how-to-get-the-top-n-elements-in-terms-of-frequency-from-a-vector-in-r?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `forcats::fct_lump`

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- read_delim("ID | Item 
1  | A    
1  | B    
2  | A    
3  | B    
1  | C    
4  | C    
5  | B    
3  | A    
4  | A    
5  | D", delim = "|", trim_ws = TRUE)


df %>% 
  mutate(Item = forcats::fct_lump(Item, n = 2))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>       ID Item 
#>    <dbl> <fct>
#>  1     1 A    
#>  2     1 B    
#>  3     2 A    
#>  4     3 B    
#>  5     1 Other
#>  6     4 Other
#>  7     5 B    
#>  8     3 A    
#>  9     4 A    
#> 10     5 Other
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

There is an argument `ties.method` with options for dealing with ties

Comment: Can u explain why ```df %>% 
  mutate(Item = forcats::fct_lump(Item, n = 3))``` results in no 'Other' appearing?

Comment: Presumably when there are four levels, there is no great advantage to reduce to three plus "others" so the function makes this decision for you

Comment: FYI I've tried this on a huge dataset of 2 million rows, where there are 500+ categories. Trying to find the Top 20 items by count using ````df %>% 
  mutate(Item = forcats::fct_lump(Item, n = 20))````, I get the error: ````Unequal factor levels: coercing to character binding character and factor vector````, and it keeps running forever

Comment: Strange. I've just made a test with with over 600 categories and 10^7 rows and it works within a few seconds. Can you make a minimally reproducible example (best to use simulated data). The error looks like one from a join or bind_rows.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is `fct_lump` from `forcats` package. Example code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
set.seed(42)

df <- tibble(
    id = sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE), 
    item = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 10, replace = TRUE))

df %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(item = forcats::fct_lump(item, 2))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
      id item 
   <int> <fct>
 1     1 A    
 2     5 A    
 3     1 B    
 4     1 Other
 5     2 B    
 6     4 B    
 7     2 Other
 8     2 Other
 9     1 A    
10     4 A
```

Comment: @RichardTelford: You are right. `w` argument makes no sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 add_count(Item) %>%
 mutate(Item = if_else(dense_rank(desc(n)) %in% 1:2, Item, "Others")) %>%
 select(-n)

      ID Item  
   <int> <chr> 
 1     1 A     
 2     1 B     
 3     2 A     
 4     3 B     
 5     1 Others
 6     4 Others
 7     5 B     
 8     3 A     
 9     4 A     
10     5 Others
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution,

```
replace(as.character(df$Item), !df$Item %in% names(table(df$Item)[1:2]), 'Others')

#[1] "A"      "B"      "A"      "B"      "Others" "Others" "B"      "A"      "A"      "Others"
```